# HP Procurve 2512/2524 protected port, source port filter or similar?

Tags: networking, switch, hp-procurve

HP Procurve switches usually have a setting so that the ports are told which other ports they can communicate with. An easy setup using this is to only allow communication with the uplink, so that no clients on LAN can see each other or communicate directly.

On a 2600 there is `filter source port`
On a 2510 it is `protected-ports`

Is this feature available on a 2524 or 2512 running firmware F.05.77? Maybe it is under a different name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 2524 and 2512 it is called "port-isolaton". It can be found in release notes matching your firmware. Weird thing is that I installed the F.05.77 but latest on official list is F.05.72

http://www.hp.com/rnd/support/manuals/23xx_25xx.htm

steps:

1. Enable port-isolation
2. After this all ports are marked as Uplink
3. Mark all ports that are not Uplink as Public, Private, Local, Group1, or Group2